# keep filename when compressing file in bash stream

Tags: mysql, bash, shell, compression, gzip

Request : I want keep the original filename when i compress a file using stream

I am compressing a file with a stream (very large file) with gzip -9

```
gunzip -c ./test.zip | sed 's/;;/;0;/g' | sed 's/,/;/g' | sed 's/xy_ign/xy_ign_latitude;xy_ign_longitude/' | sed 's/xy_ign/xy_geopad_latitude;xy_geopad_longitude/' | gzip -9 >test.gz
```

when i'm decompressing my file

```
gunzip test.gz
```

the result filename is **test** and not **test.csv**

I know i can use the -N option to retrieve original file name

```
gunzip -N test.gz
```

but the file is used with mysql load data infile and the load data infile need a filename to work correctly

```
mysql -u user -p -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/test.gz' INTO TABLE test FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ; SHOW WARNINGS" test_db
```

**How can i have a gzip file with the filename inside?**

Comment: What happens if you use `test.csv.gz` as the filename?

Answer (score 0):

gzip will, by default, store the original file name and file modification time in the gzip header. However gzip would need to be invoked with the file name. E.g.

```
gzip foo
mv foo.gz bar.gz
gunzip -N bar.gz
```

will produce `foo`.